# how to import Java classes from diff projects

Tags: java, import, classpath

Here is the example.

**1. proj1/src/com/test/proj1/A.java**

```
package com.test.proj1;
// java utility class
public class A {  
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test() method is called in class A");
    }}
```

**2. proj2/src/com/test/proj2/MainClass.java**

```
package com.test.proj2;
import com.test.proj1;  
// Java class for executing program  
public class MainClass {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println("static main is called in MainClass");  
        A a1 = new A();  
        a1.test(); 
    }}
```

3. Now I am trying to compile both of them and get the following error:

> javac -d ./proj1/classes ./proj1/src/com/test/proj1/A.java
>
> javac -d ./proj2/classes -cp ./proj1/classes
>
> ./proj2/src/com/test/proj2/MainClass.java

**3 errors**

Please help to tell me the correct way for the above scenario.
Thanks.

Comment: with an import statement. just make sure the class is in the classpath

Comment: Sorry for the partial post: I finally post the code snips and the command lines

Comment: `import com.test.proj1;` is not sufficient - you have to actually import the class you want to use: `import com.test.proj1.A;` or use a wildcard import: `import com.test.proj1.*;`

Comment: Great. I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your classes in `JAR`. Import it, and use it.

Comment: With the full sample code files, could you help to point out the the correct way for the errors?

Comment: Yes. the error comes from import. As what Jesper said, I missed the reference. Thank you guys.